# Implementing an IDManager in Java - efficient way

Tags: java

IDManager API provides 2 methods

1. get_ID() - which generates an unique id everytime it is called and returns it,
2. free_ID(id) - frees the passed in id and freed id should be able to be reused later.

Could you please help me on how to approach this problem efficiently? - as in best DS to use, what's the best way to store and maintain ids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Store the used ID's in a `HashSet`, and keep the last generated ID in a separate variable.**

When someone calls `get_ID`, increment the last generated ID and verify that it's not in the `HashSet`.  Continue doing this until you find an ID that's not in the HashSet.  When you find one that isn't in the `HashSet`, add it and return the value.

When someone calls `free_ID(id)`, simply remove it from the `HashSet`.

For the first 2.1 billion calls to `get_ID`, the ID value will just continue incrementing, giving out unique ID's with every call.  Then, the integer will roll around and start re-using ID's.  At that point, the code that checks to see if it's in the `HashMap` will kick in, and the `get_ID` method will start taking longer as it continues to check values looking for an unused one.

If this becomes a problem where there are billions of requests coming in for ID values, then you can create a `Queue` to hold ID's which have been used and freed.  Once the ID value reaches its maximum, then you can start assigning values from the front of the queue instead of incrementing a counter and searching.  I would only add this part, however, if it is necessary as it will require 8 GB of RAM to hold the entire list.

One other possibility is that you want your ID's to always be the lowest possible value.  If this is the case, then you should use the `Queue` as described above, but have `get_ID` check the queue before incrementing and generating a new ID.  This way, if there are any freed ID numbers, they'll be used before a new higher value is created.  This queue would only be as large as you have ID's which are no longer being used, so it will scale to the size of your requirements.